# Mac OS X Server 10.6: Change hostname/DNS name of running server

Tags: mac-osx-server

Because DynDNS stopped offering a specific domain name, my customer had to change this.
This will end up in changing the server settings at all.

Situation:

- Mac Mini Server with MacOS Server 10.6.8
- The services AFP, SMB, Calendar, Addressbook, Kerberos are configured and running
- Some domain users are configured
- Existing DNS name of the server is server.degkro.homedns.org
- The new DNS name will be server.degkro.dyndns-home.com

I know that for some parts I have to use scutil, but I'm not sure, if this does change every occurrence of the old DNS name to the new DNS name.
How about Kerberos? Isn't it that way, that I have to shutdown Kerberos, to be able to change the Realm and LDP Search Base but then also all Domain Users will be deleted?

What I'm searching for is a Step-by-Step description to have a error-free change of DNS entries for all services on the server.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to change the Kerberos realm and the LDAP search base. Having these to reflect the DNS name is a convenient convention, but not a strict requirement.

Changing the Kerberos configuration wouldn't be all that difficult, but I have no idea how OpenDirectory or the LDAP part of it would react to a change of the base DN. In the general case of a Linux OpenLDAP server it would be easy (exporting the data, modify the LDIF files, import back in), but the tricky part might be the references to the password server database that OpenDirectory uses. For a guide to change the KDC data, please refer [to this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3655) guide from Apple. It works, I did this :)

For AFP/SMB, the DNS name is largely irrelevant, it just answers when talked to on the assigned port.

Can't comment on the groupware stuff.

Answer (score 0):

`changeip`

```
Usage: changeip <oldIP> [<newIP>] [<oldHost> <newHost>]
Change IP addresses and host names in supported files, e.g.
changeip 10.0.1.10 10.0.1.12 server10.example.com server12.example.com
```